Can't convert a record from PostgreSQL with EF Core to a usable
I struggle to get the result of a SqlQueryRaw (EF Core) from a PostgreSQL db.
I have the following query :
select 
    case 
        
        when ... then (col1, col2)
        when ... then
        case when ... then (col1, col2)
             when ... then (col1, col2)
             when ... then (col1, col2)
             when ... then (col1, col2)
        end
    end as "Result"
    from ...

It returns something like that in a single column named "Result" :
(0.48000000000000000000,474579)
(3.2051000000000000,474581)
(0.92050000000000000000,474582)
Here is my EF Core code :
await _dbContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<...>(sql, paramObjects).ToListAsync()
My problem is that I struggle to retrieve the result of my query. It tried to set the result as a string, string[], decimal, tuples, even in a test object : public class test { public ... Result { get; set; } }.
The error tell me that the result is a record, but how can I convert it ?
I'd like to stick to ef core in this case if possible.

Try move everything into subquery and expand tuple: select s.* from (your_current_query) s Then you should be able to read this result.
